# Eclipse soundpool loading error

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to develop a library management software for android using Eclipse. So far my application is running fine (in eclipse emulator), but I am getting some errors which is bugging me (though there is no visible impact on functionality). If anybody can guide me, I'll appreciate a lot.

Error # 1: Whenever I press any button (or action items), I keep getting soundpool errors (in logcat) like below. I didn't manually load/assign any sound effect to anything, hence these must have been default sounds.

```
11-08 23:05:58.466: E/SoundPool(374): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-08 23:05:58.466: W/AudioService(374): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-08 23:05:58.466: E/SoundPool(374): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-08 23:05:58.466: W/AudioService(374): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
```

Error # 2: When I run my application to my virtual device manager, I got below error messages (in logcat) during initialization, which i have no idea of, and which does not have any visible impact on my application as well.

```
11-08 23:16:10.226: E/memtrack(1110): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-08 23:16:10.226: E/android.os.Debug(1110): failed to load memtrack module: -2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, don't worry about those errors. They're not directly caused by your application, and they have no visible impact. It's just noise in the log.

The first one is given simply because the emulator can't find the default "I hit a button" sound. Most likely, it was not included in the emulator image. Nevertheless, it will try to play the sound when you hit a button. You can probably stop this from happening by going into the AVD's settings app (in the emulator) and disabling the option to play sounds for UI events and keyboard presses.

The second just means that it had a problem loading {some} hardware module. This could be something to do with GPU support, sdcard handling, basically anything. Given that there are many hardware differences between an emulator and an actual device, this isn't very surprising. Again, if it isn't causing any problems, don't worry about it. My AVDs show the same message, and I've yet to see any issues.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of these media errors you need to go to settings section at emulator device and turn the sounds off, the touch sounds, unlock sounds and other.