# Couldn't load memtrack module Logcat Error

Tags: android, logcat, stack-trace

I am getting an error `Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory) failed to load memtrack module: -2` at run time.

**StackTrace Error:**

```
 E/SoundPool(1280)       : error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 
 E/SoundPool(1280)       : error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg       
 E/SurfaceFlinger(931)   : glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 733995180
 E/memtrack(1873)        : Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
 E/android.os.Debug(1873): failed to load memtrack module: -2
 E/libEGL(931)           : called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL(931)           : called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL(931)           : called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL(931)           : called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/SurfaceFlinger(931)   : glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 733995180
 E/SurfaceFlinger(931)   : got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
 E/libEGL(931)           : called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 E/libEGL(931)           : called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hive"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.sit.gems.app.GemsApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
            android:name="com.sit.gems.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sit.gems.activity.HomeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**SplashActivity.java:**

```
package com.sit.gems.activity;
import com.example.hive.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_home);
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
        SplashActivity.this.finish();
    }

}
```

**layout_home.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_home"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_video"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_audio"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_blog"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_gal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_more"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
                android:divider="@null" />

            <!-- android:background="#d8e49c" -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

Finally it displays the blank screen.

[image]

Anybody know how to solve these errors?

Comment: did you resolve your problem ?

Comment: @Cocorico no i doesnt resolve these problem yet.Did you know?

Comment: I think you have a pb with OpenGl. Did you use an emulator or a pysical device ?

Comment: @Cocorico I am using an emulator.

Comment: @Cocorico i never use opengl in these project

Comment: I think Android use OpenGl in its system. Do you use the eclipse's emulator ?

Comment: Maybe Try this : http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: but does it crash when app is lunched or when compiling ?

Comment: @Cocorico it displays the blank screen

Comment: ok I think it's an OpenGl pb. What does GenyMotion do ? does it work ?

Comment: emulator works fast for me.I thought geny motion is not useful for me bcoz my emulator works fastly.geny motion only usage is to increase the speed of emulator thats it.Thats y i didnt installed yet

Comment: But does your app work with Geny ?

Comment: my emulator was working fine.Now I got a stacktrace error.If I run a some other project I am getting a  output in emulator.But in these project i am getting an error.I didnt installed geny bcoz its only usage is to increase the speed of emulator.But My emulator works fastly till now.

Comment: ok. I have only one solution. Recreate a blank project and copy all your classes in it. Maybe it will correct this pb.

Comment: @Cocorico I tried what you said but now also `blank screen` would be displayed.

Comment: Hum, maybe try to create an Android blank project and find differences between this blank project and your project (in dependies, manifest, buildPath or other)

Comment: @Cocorico everything would be fine.

Comment: *dependencies. 
try to put this in onResume function : 
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class)); and replace SlashActivity by this

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872307/eclipse-soundpool-loading-error

Comment: @user2450263 that wasn't useful for me

Comment: The second part answer in that link? it explains what the differences could be in emulator, did you try the same on a device

Comment: @user2450263 that wasnt solved

Comment: What do you have in `layout_home.xml`?

Comment: @shoerat TabHost xml code

Comment: @shoerat u need to see that code?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is very relevant code.

Comment: @shoerat check it I edited and include that xml file

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This error, as you can read on [the question linked in comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error/22745487#comment34571006_22629568), results to be:

> "[...] a problem with loading {some} hardware module. This could be something to do with GPU support, sdcard handling, basically anything."

The step 1 below should resolve this problem. Also as I can see, you have some strange package names inside your manifest:

- *package="com.example.hive"* in `<manifest>` tag,
- *android:name="com.sit.gems.app.GemsApplication"* for `<application>`
- and *android:name="com.sit.gems.activity"* in `<activity>`

As you know, these things do not prevent your app to be displayed. But I think:

> the `Couldn't load memtrack module error` could occur because of emulators configurations problems and, because your project contains many organization problems, it might help to give a fresh redesign.

For better using and with few things, this can be resolved by following these tips:

---

#### 1. Try another emulator...

And even a real device! The `memtrack module` error seems related to your emulator. So change it into `Run configuration`, don't forget to change the `API` too.

---

#### 2. OpenGL error logs

For `OpenGl` errors, as `called unimplemented OpenGL ES API`, it's not an error but a statement! You should enable it in your manifest (you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273549/2668136) if you're using GLSurfaceView inside `HomeActivity.java`, it might help you):

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"></uses-feature>  
// or
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" android:required="true" />
```

---

#### 3.  Use the same package

Don't declare different package names to all the tags in `Manifest`. You should have the same for `Manifest`, `Activities`, etc. Something like this looks right:

```
<!-- set the general package -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sit.gems.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- don't set a package name in <application> -->
    <application ... >

        <!-- then, declare the activities -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.sit.gems.activity.SplashActivity" ... >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- same package here -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.sit.gems.activity.HomeActivity" ... >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

#### 4. Don't get lost with layouts:

You should set another layout for `SplashScreenActivity.java` because you're not using the `TabHost` for the splash screen and this is not a safe resource way. Declare a specific layout with something different, like the app name and the logo:

```
// inside SplashScreen class
setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

// layout splash_screen.xml
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="@string/appname" />
```

Avoid using a layout in activities which don't use it.

---

#### 5. Splash Screen?

Finally, I don't understand clearly the purpose of your `SplashScreenActivity`. It sets a content view and directly finish. This is useless.

As its name is *Splash Screen*, I assume that you want to display a screen before launching your `HomeActivity`. Therefore, you should do this *and don't use the `TabHost` layout ;)*:

```
// FragmentActivity is also useless here! You don't use a Fragment into it, so, use traditional Activity
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // set your splash_screen layout
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    
        // create a new Thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // sleep during 800ms
                    Thread.sleep(800);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // start HomeActivity
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I hope this kind of tips help you to achieve what you want.
If it's not the case, let me know how can I help you.

Comment: I am using the `TabHost in layout_home.xml`

Comment: And why do you have nothing in SplashScreenActivity? This activity displays your TabHost?

Comment: *I repeat* I'm not sure but you should try at least 1, 2 and 4. Hope this helps!

Comment: ya sure.I am trying it.will tell you the results later on.

Comment: I followed each and every steps what you are told.But after implementing that I am getting the same kind of stacktrace error.

Comment: Did you create another emulator?

Comment: Damn! Sorry. I'll delete my answer, I hope you will resolve your issue. Good luck!

Comment: dont delete this answer

Comment: may be these will be resolved to someone else I thought.thats why I am gonna give +1 for these.

Comment: Thank you too for your guidance :)

Comment: Let me know if you achieve what you want ^^ Good luck

Comment: I doesn't know I can able to resolve these errors.But I have to try it until I get the result.

Comment: I try to find a solution with the help of your answer.Hope I can able to get a output today.I am trying to add some codes with the help of your answer.

Comment: I got a output.Your answer helpful to me.you are great.I done what ever you said. finally I created and add one method named blogSelected .These Project is related to display a blogs.I think its my mistake to missed that method.If I am not change the package name as you said I cant get the output.Your answer really helpful to me. thank you.Have a nice day.

Comment: Ahh I'm very glad to help you! Happy coding bro.

Comment: In my case app is running fine on android 7, 8 and 9 but for Lollipop (5.0) facing the same kind of issues "Couldn't load memtrack module: -2" and " ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 504x504", tried everything but nothing worked

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error. Creating a new AVD with the appropriate API level solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but When I changed the skin of AVD device to HVGA, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be because of easy problem.

This is my case:

> In project, we are using *Kotlin* and *DI* wiht *Dagger2*. Our data model class changed in API. However, we forget update it in application side. Thus, I had same error which is ***memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module***.

My case solution:

1. Update data model in App.
2. Click ***"Clean Project"*** on Android Studio.
3. Click ***"Rebuild Project"*** on Android Studio.
4. Done.

Answer (score -2):

do you called the ViewTreeObserver and not remove it.

```
    mEtEnterlive.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
         // do nothing here can cause such problem
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue too, also running on an emulator.. The same message was showing up on Logcat, but it wasn't affecting the functionality of the app. But it was annoying, and I don't like seeing errors on the log that I don't understand.

Anyway, I got rid of the message by **increasing the RAM** on the emulator.