# Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-sdk-tools

Update: After I removed and reinstalled bundle problem only remains on emulator

I've just installed the android development bundle on my windows 8 laptop. I'm trying to install the first app "hello world" (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) to my Nexus 7 (2012) version 4.4.2 but its not working.

Using the logcat viewer (whilst the build is taking place) I can see it is reporting:

> "Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)" followed by
>   " failed to load memtrack module: -2 at run time."

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Console output:

```
[2014-04-04 15:18:35 - myFirstApplication] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared

[2014-04-04 15:18:43 - myFirstApplication] ------------------------------

[2014-04-04 15:18:43 - myFirstApplication] Android Launch!

[2014-04-04 15:18:43 - myFirstApplication] adb is running normally.

[2014-04-04 15:18:43 - myFirstApplication] No Launcher activity found!

[2014-04-04 15:18:43 - myFirstApplication] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

[2014-04-04 15:18:43 - myFirstApplication] Performing sync

[2014-04-04 15:18:44 - myFirstApplication] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'mydeviceinfo'

[2014-04-04 15:18:44 - myFirstApplication] Uploading myFirstApplication.apk onto device 'mydeviceinfo'
[2014-04-04 15:18:44 - myFirstApplication] Installing myFirstApplication.apk...

[2014-04-04 15:18:47 - myFirstApplication] Success!

[2014-04-04 15:18:47 - myFirstApplication] \myFirstApplication\bin\myFirstApplication.apk installed on device

[2014-04-04 15:18:47 - myFirstApplication] Done!
"
```

I've started looking at a similar post [Couldn't load memtrack module Logcat Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error) but i can't see what i would need to do for this situation

Comment: Just noticed I get this on the emulator too

Comment: Did you have an `<activity>` inside your manifest or did you create an `Activity` Class inside your app? I think you should create a HelloActivity..

Comment: No I just followed the first example and created a 'BlankActivity' from the new android application wizard. I expected the app to build and just load a blank page

Comment: This kind of error is difficult to debug, because it can appear for anything. Like your output said: `No Launcher activity found! ... The launch will only sync the application package on the device!`, it might be the cause. Try to add a default `MainActivity` (it was created normally) and add it to your manifest as action: `MAIN` and category: `LAUNCHER`. You will see in **Declaring the activity in the manifest**: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Creating HTH

Comment: unfortunatley that didnt work. I've uninstalled and reinstalled too. This time though when I created a new project it added the MainActivity automattically. I've updated my original post to show my full manifest xml now

Comment: Update: After trying this on the real nexus it works!!!!! Its just the emulator causing the problem now! Thank you so much for your help @Fllo, Ive been trying to get this working for 20 hours. really appreciate your comments and help

Comment: Very glad to help. As you seen on my SO answer that you linked, it was the step 1. ;) This error occurs mainly on emulators. Happy Coding!

Comment: Answered it here for `Xamarin` developer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707459/1876355

Answer (score 9):

If there is a newer version (compare to the version code defined in your manifest.xml) of the same Application in the target emulator, you will get error as you mentioned.

**Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)**

**failed to load memtrack module: -2**

Answer (score 7):

I faced this error several days ago. if your real device or emulator already contains older version of application you are trying to run, then uninstall this old version and run again.It has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, make sure you're running the project in the right emulator, sometimes Eclipse doesn't ask you about the emulator that it will use.

Go to the Run menu, Run Configurations, in the left list pick Android Application and then the application that you're trying to run. In the left panel pick the "Target" tab and choose the option "Always prompt to pick device" and try to run again.

Make sure to pick the right emulator, in my case I had recently installed blue stacks and Eclipse was trying to run the application on it without prompting me, instead running it on the regular emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because of a missing Semicolon in the java file ";". So do check for proper closing of the code Statements