# What does this mean? Android Studio logcat: "Couldn't load memtrack module"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications, logcat, android-audiomanager

In Android Studio, after clicking "run", while loading either a device or any of various Android emulator devices,  logcat initially indicates the following errors:

- E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
- E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2

The app does contain an mp3 in /java/res/raw directory but not sure if this is the file that fails to load.

App functionality and widgets all seem to work normally.
App seems to play the mp3 normally when fired via BroadcastReceiver / AudioManager / NotificationCompat.Builder.

Any Ideas on correcting the logcat error? or is there even a need to?

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error

Comment: Or this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862929/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Thank you Michal, I'll look deeper into these.  Surprised my google search didn't return these stackoverflow answers.