# App crashes when trying to use JavaMail for Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use the JavaMail Android port in my application but my app crashes when I try to send anything. I've followed the guide [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) and created the `Mail`class. Then in my `MainActivity` I've added

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Mail m = new Mail("mailtosendfrom", "mypassword");
    new SendMailTask().execute(m);
}

private class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Mail, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Mail... mail) {
        Mail m = mail[0];

        String[] toArr = {"mailtosendto"};
        m.setTo(toArr);
        m.setFrom("mailtosendfrom");
        m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device.");
        m.setBody("Email body.");
        try {
            m.send();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackage" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now when I start my app it crashes immediately with the following message in logcat:

```
04-19 18:37:58.540    4547-4547/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-19 18:37:58.540    4547-4547/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is ON
04-19 18:37:58.570    4547-4547/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-19 18:37:58.570    4547-4547/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-19 18:37:58.590    4547-4547/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
    --------- beginning of system
04-19 18:37:58.590    1313-1823/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.oskar.ratingapp appid=10046 user=0: from pid 4547
04-19 18:37:58.600    4547-4547/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-19 18:37:58.600    4547-4550/? I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
04-19 18:37:58.600    4547-4556/? E/art﹕ Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
04-19 18:37:58.600    4547-4556/? I/AndroidRuntime﹕ NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_1' failed
04-19 18:37:58.990    4559-4559/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-19 18:37:58.990    4559-4559/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is ON
04-19 18:37:59.030    4559-4559/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-19 18:37:59.030    4559-4559/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-19 18:37:59.050    4559-4559/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
04-19 18:37:59.060    1313-1804/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.oskar.ratingapp/.MainActivity} from uid 0 on display 0
04-19 18:37:59.070    4559-4559/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-19 18:37:59.080    1313-1330/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.oskar.ratingapp for activity com.oskar.ratingapp/.MainActivity: pid=4569 uid=10046 gids={50046, 9997, 3003} abi=x86_64
04-19 18:37:59.080    4559-4561/? I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
04-19 18:37:59.080    4569-4569/? E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10046: Read-only file system
04-19 18:37:59.080    4569-4569/? W/Zygote﹕ createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
04-19 18:37:59.080    4569-4569/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-19 18:37:59.330    4569-4585/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-19 18:37:59.350    4569-4569/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fb32fc8f280, tid 4569
04-19 18:37:59.370    4569-4569/? D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-19 18:37:59.430    4569-4585/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fb32fc8ff40, tid 4585
04-19 18:37:59.440    4569-4585/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-19 18:37:59.460    4569-4585/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-19 18:37:59.480    4569-4585/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-19 18:37:59.480    4569-4585/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fb32fc8ef00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    --------- beginning of crash
04-19 18:37:59.610    4569-4584/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x750000013f in tid 4584 (AsyncTask #1)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86_64/sdk_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:5.0/LRX09D/1504858:eng/test-keys'
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ ABI: 'x86_64'
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 4569, tid: 4584, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> com.oskar.ratingapp <<<
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x750000013f
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ rax 0000000000000000  rbx 000000750000008f  rcx 0000000000000081  rdx 0000000000000001
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ rsi 000000000000001e  rdi 00007fb33a7a72b0
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8  000000000000014a  r9  0000000000000000  r10 00007fb33e64fe2c  r11 00007fb3410b12c0
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ r12 00007fb32fc91380  r13 0000000000000001  r14 00007fb32fccf268  r15 00007fb32fccf380
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ cs  0000000000000033  ss  000000000000002b
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ rip 00007fb3411144d6  rbp 0000000000000000  rsp 00007fb32fbfeb30  eflags 0000000000010202
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 00000000000e34d6  /system/lib64/libcrypto.so (ENGINE_init+38)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 00000000000eb435  /system/lib64/libcrypto.so (EVP_MD_CTX_copy_ex+37)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 pc 00000000000f8582  /system/lib64/libcrypto.so (HMAC_CTX_copy+66)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03 pc 00000000000f7e32  /system/lib64/libcrypto.so
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04 pc 00000000000f698a  /system/lib64/libcrypto.so (EVP_PKEY_CTX_dup+234)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05 pc 00000000000eb52b  /system/lib64/libcrypto.so (EVP_MD_CTX_copy_ex+283)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06 pc 000000000004a9b3  /system/lib64/libssl.so (tls1_mac+195)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07 pc 0000000000032456  /system/lib64/libssl.so
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08 pc 000000000003207e  /system/lib64/libssl.so (ssl3_write_bytes+302)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09 pc 00000000000261d0  /system/lib64/libssl.so (ssl3_do_write+32)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10 pc 0000000000028ef1  /system/lib64/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+2353)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #11 pc 00000000000207d7  /system/lib64/libssl.so (ssl23_connect+3463)
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #12 pc 00000000000186a2  /system/lib64/libjavacrypto.so
04-19 18:37:59.730      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ #13 pc 0000000000409ef1  /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/system@framework@boot.oat
04-19 18:37:59.800      957-957/? I/DEBUG﹕ Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01
04-19 18:37:59.840    1313-1399/system_process W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '27028e74 com.oskar.ratingapp/com.oskar.ratingapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-19 18:37:59.840    1313-1399/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '27028e74 com.oskar.ratingapp/com.oskar.ratingapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-19 18:37:59.840      963-963/? I/Zygote﹕ Process 4569 exited due to signal (11)
04-19 18:37:59.940    1313-4593/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.oskar.ratingapp/.MainActivity
04-19 18:37:59.950    1313-1822/system_process I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{27028e74 u0 com.oskar.ratingapp/com.oskar.ratingapp.MainActivity}
04-19 18:37:59.950    1313-1822/system_process W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '27028e74 com.oskar.ratingapp/com.oskar.ratingapp.MainActivity (server)'
04-19 18:37:59.950    1313-4593/system_process E/ActivityManager﹕ Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 360x360
04-19 18:37:59.950    1313-4593/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Exception thrown during pause
    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:479)
            at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:701)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:852)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2754)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2611)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2448)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11507)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11404)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12083)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11599)
            at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
04-19 18:37:59.950      946-946/? E/lowmemorykiller﹕ Error opening /proc/4569/oom_score_adj; errno=2
04-19 18:37:59.960    1313-1329/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.oskar.ratingapp (pid 4569) has died
04-19 18:38:00.000    1313-2329/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-19 18:38:00.010    1903-1968/com.android.launcher W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-19 18:38:00.010    1903-1968/com.android.launcher W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fb32dde2980, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-19 18:38:00.010    1313-2329/system_process W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-19 18:38:00.010    1313-2329/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fb328cf1780, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-19 18:38:03.090    1313-1426/system_process D/TaskPersister﹕ removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=44_task.xml
04-19 18:38:03.200    1313-1414/system_process W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
04-19 18:38:03.220    1313-1463/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@12273a0d attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@133a0350
04-19 18:38:03.740    1903-1968/com.android.launcher W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
```

Comment: did you gave this "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> " in your manifest file?

Comment: Post the entire error.

Comment: can you put your full log..

Comment: @Oskar Where is the crash exception? It would look like `04-19 18:13:42.200    3730-3746/com.oskar.ratingapp E/`. With an `E`.

Comment: Added more now, I removed  the filter in logcat for only my app.

Comment: Now it is more clear. One thing I am seeing is your are trying to `Toast` in the `doInBackground`. You cannot do this as it is not in the UI thread.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I updated code and output

Comment: That wasn't supposed to fix it. I am just removing one problem at a time. Have you tried compiling this without the code? Does the jar even compile with Android? You need to try more things, not juts copy and paste from the site.

Comment: `Transport.send(msg)` in `send` in the `Mail` class seems to be the problem. Removing that stops the rest of the app from crashing.

Comment: Nice! But does the email send now?

Comment: Nope. I guess that is the part that should send it

Comment: @Oskar Why do you need this anyways? You want to send mail without using Gmail?

Comment: @Oskar Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error

Comment: @JaredBurrows I want to send mail without requiring any user interaction

Comment: Is the log output above from your most recent failure?  Note that the code you copied includes these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: @BillShannon Yes it is. I followed the suggestions for the common mistakes but it still crashes.

Comment: I'm not an Android expert, but the crash doesn't seem to have anything to do with the use of JavaMail.  It's hard to believe removing the Transport.send avoids the crash.

Comment: @BillShannon Then what can the issue be?

Comment: No idea.  You need an Android expert.

Comment: @BillShannon Hmm... Thought this would be a more common feature.

Comment: Lots and lots of people have made JavaMail work on Android.  I don't know what's unique about your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not the problem, the emulator is.

I just tried this on a device instead of the emulator and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

complete shot in the dark. This has worked for me however.

try this

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
es.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Run Mail Here
    }
});
es.shutdown();
//This part is so that you know when the ES has finished so that you can persay say success.
try {
    boolean finshed = es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I had an issue with AsyncTasks earlier. Hope it helps!