# How to resolve manifest error?

Tags: android, android-activity, package

hi iam facing unable to start activity in android. I am using different packages... so please help me... when i run this application it is giving below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="yougotag.com.pharmatnt" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/yougotag"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/NewTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".usermanagement.usercreation.LoginActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".usermanagement.usercreation.AccountInformation"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".usermanagement.usercreation.PersonalInfo"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".usermanagement.usercreation.AddressInfo"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".usermanagement.usercreation.TermsConditions"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".usermanagement.usercreation.ConsentActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".usermanagement.usercreation.SettingsDeletion"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>

            <activity android:name=".usermanagement.usercreation.VerifyAccountActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".passwordmanagement.ForgotUniqueIdActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".passwordmanagement.SendUniqueIdActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".passwordmanagement.ForgotPasswordActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".passwordmanagement.SendPasswordActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".passwordmanagement.HomeActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
            <activity android:name=".passwordmanagement.ChangePasswordNewActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>



        </application>

    </manifest>
```

My error is like this...

```
 04-23 19:10:13.000: E/cutils-trace(5674): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-23 19:10:13.214: E/memtrack(5674): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-23 19:10:13.214: E/android.os.Debug(5674): failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-23 19:10:13.824: E/cutils-trace(5693): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-23 19:10:14.007: E/memtrack(5693): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-23 19:10:14.007: E/android.os.Debug(5693): failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704): Process: yougotag.com.pharmatnt, PID: 5704
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yougotag.com.pharmatnt/yougotag.com.pharmatnt.usermanagement.usercreation.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1333)
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5304)
04-23 19:10:14.244: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

So please tell me how to resolve it... i am facing problem...

Comment: remove this and run .usermanagement.usercreation with ."ur activity name"

Comment: post you complete manifest file.

Comment: i edited ...please check

Comment: as @micky said can you replace .usermanagement.usercreation.LoginActivity with yougotag.com.pharmatnt.LoginActivity and try.

Comment: Fortunately, but not sure I found something similar error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error please check

Comment: what is the package name of `LoginActivity`?

Comment: it's works fine boss..

Answer (score 1):

In my manifest file everything pointing right way... but two things i did mistake
1) our package name must in small letters only
2) in oncreate method i gave wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

You wrongly referred your activity name in manifest. There is no activity which named

```
.usermanagement.usercreation.LoginActivity
```

By using . operator you can directly access your Activity. So remove the App name before the Activity name.

Thanks

Comment: i am unable to under stand... LoginActivity in under UserManagement under user creation. So i put like that

Comment: Ok then post your whole logcat?

Comment: Ok please post your complete LoginActivity as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the target SDK and the min SDK version, so add :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You package in manifest tag(line no. 3) is-
yougotag.com.pharmatnt

You have given launching Activity name like this-
.usermanagement.usercreation.LoginActivity

The '.' notation at the first indicates that your activity is in below path-
yougotag.com.pharmatnt\usermanagement.usercreation.LoginActivity

(package\your activty name)

So provide right package name in manifest tag