# Installation Error Unknown Failure

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have fallen into strange issue.
I have a project that was working find on android 4.4.4.
Last night I upgraded my phone to 5.0.2.
Now when I am trying to debug my application over it. I am getting strange error.

**Console:**

Installation error: Unknown failure

Please check logcat output for more details.

Launch canceled!

**LogCat:**

[image]

**Manifest**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gs.gssdk.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!--
    Declare this required feature if you want to make the app available to BLE-capable
    devices only.  If you want to make your app available to devices that don't support BLE,
    you should omit this in the manifest.  Instead, determine BLE capability by using
    PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)
    -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     
     
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
     
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.gs.gssdk.sample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <service
            android:name = "com.gs.gssdk.BluetoothLeService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have researched links but no help.

I am unable to solve this issue.

Can you help me?

Comment: You can see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a try but no gain.

Comment: Just uninstall your app from phone and debug it, if still have problem just increase your target sdk version to 21

Answer (score 0):

My phone was not set up for USB debugging. I checked that check box in developer options and now its working great.
Thanks.