# Android application is not launching due to emulator issue

Tags: android

I am trying to run my Android application but I'm getting this error:

```
05-26 17:06:30.362: D/AndroidRuntime(8981):
Calling main entry  com.android.commands.pm.Pm
05-26 17:08:46.372: D/AndroidRuntime(9000): >>>>>>
AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
05-26 17:08:46.372: D/AndroidRuntime(9000): CheckJNI is OFF
05-26 17:08:46.372: D/dalvikvm(9000): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
05-26 17:08:46.422: D/dalvikvm(9000): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
05-26 17:08:46.422: D/dalvikvm(9000): 
Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so  0x0
05-26 17:08:46.422: D/dalvikvm(9000): 
Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
05-26 17:08:46.422: D/dalvikvm(9000): 
No JNI_OnLoad found in   libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
05-26 17:08:46.442: D/dalvikvm(9000): 
Note: class  Landroid/app/  ActivityManagerNative ; 
has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
05-26 17:08:46.522: E/memtrack(9000):
Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
05-26 17:08:46.522: E/android.os.Debug(9000):
failed to load memtrack   module: - 2
05-26 17:08:46.552: D/AndroidRuntime(9000):
Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Couldn't load memtrack module Logcat Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error)

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest you something, kill adb ,restart eclips and run emullator again.
else go for new updates, go to help->check for updates. if found new updates install it.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean but your "answer" is too generic, and IMHO unlikely to solve her problem. Did you actually face the same memtrack module and solved it by killing adb ? Me solving her problem and your "answer" are completely unrelated things.

Comment: thnks for your remarks, and for helping people. but you know i had a problem with emulator, i was not able to run the app and the emulator in ddms showed online, i solved my problem, i saw a line in her post which was same like my problem,
*** Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)***

Comment: that error is very often due to misconfiguration in the AVD. Launching the same one again is likely to reproduce the problem. Creating a new one, ensuring the proper parameters are set for GPU support and the API level is probably a better option.

Comment: kindly post your answer, to help her.

Comment: When the answer is essentially a shorter version of another answer to the same question on this site, it is preferred to mark the question as a duplicate, which I did (you can see a comment directly below the question).