# Failed to install apk on device 'emulator-5554! launch canceled

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked many times but none of solution seem to work for me.
I'm trying to make an app which displays google map when it starts,but app gets stopped every time I try to launch it in my device.
I tried to restart my emulator several times and tried to install apk several times in emulator ,but it failed to install.

**here is my logcat output:-**

```
   11-11 02:30:00.317: I/Choreographer(1025): Skipped 85 frames!  The                                    application may be doing too much work on its main thread.                       
   11-11 02:30:17.937: D/AndroidRuntime(1465): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
   11-11 02:30:18.049: D/AndroidRuntime(1465): CheckJNI is ON
   11-11 02:30:19.803: E/memtrack(1465): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
   11-11 02:30:19.804: E/android.os.Debug(1465): failed to load memtrack module: -2
   11-11 02:30:20.528: D/AndroidRuntime(1465): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
   11-11 02:30:21.191: D/DefContainer(699): Copying /data/local/tmp/Map1.apk to base.apk
   11-11 02:30:21.940: I/PackageParser(351): com.example.map1: compat added       android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
   11-11 02:30:22.492: I/art(351): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8852(660KB) AllocSpace objects, 10(276KB) LOS objects, 15% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 6.889ms total 157.656ms
   11-11 02:30:27.443: I/art(351): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 22779(835KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(75KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 6.491ms total 170.123ms
   11-11 02:30:28.229: I/art(351): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4848(221KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(167KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 8MB/8MB, paused 7.096ms total 139.759ms
   11-11 02:30:28.410: D/PackageManager(351): Renaming /data/app/vmdl872362061.tmp to /data/app/com.example.map1-3
   11-11 02:30:28.513: I/ActivityManager(351): Force stopping com.example.map1 appid=10061 user=-1: uninstall pkg
   11-11 02:30:28.814: I/art(351): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2233(152KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 8MB/8MB, paused 11.324ms total 68.953ms
   11-11 02:30:29.040: I/PackageManager(351): Package com.example.map1 codePath changed from /data/app/com.example.map1-1 to /data/app/com.example.map1-3; Retaining data and using new
   11-11 02:30:29.262: I/art(351): DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.map1-3@base.apk@classes.dex' for file location '/data/app/com.example.map1-3/base.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
   11-11 02:30:29.270: I/art(351): DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/app/com.example.map1-3/arm/base.odex' for file location '/data/app/com.example.map1-3/base.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
   11-11 02:30:29.271: I/PackageManager(351): Running dexopt on: /data/app/com.example.map1-3/base.apk pkg=com.example.map1 isa=arm vmSafeMode=false
   11-11 02:30:29.749: I/dex2oat(1476): /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=6 --zip-location=/data/app/com.example.map1-3/base.apk --oat-fd=7 --oat-location=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.map1-3@base.apk@classes.dex --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m
   11-11 02:30:37.467: I/art(351): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1520(182KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 3% free, 8MB/8MB, paused 16.720ms total 235.626ms
   11-11 02:30:43.765: W/dex2oat(1476): Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
   11-11 02:30:58.559: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of java.lang.String android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost$SavedState.toString() took 100.137ms
   11-11 02:31:00.358: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$Token.<init>(java.lang.Object) took 343.659ms
   11-11 02:31:01.044: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$Token.writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel, int) took 682.459ms
   11-11 02:31:01.220: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.obtain(android.content.Context, java.lang.Object) took 168.135ms
   11-11 02:31:17.160: I/art(595): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8483(413KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 1608KB/2MB, paused 4.648ms total 208.707ms
   11-11 02:31:17.163: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of java.util.ArrayList com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzo.zzd(com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzo) took 290.814ms
   11-11 02:31:17.483: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of com.google.android.gms.location.places.personalized.PlaceUserData com.google.android.gms.location.places.personalized.zze.zzeG(android.os.Parcel) took 128.367ms
   11-11 02:31:19.315: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.model.moments.ItemScopeEntity com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.model.moments.zza.zzfK(android.os.Parcel) took 475.791ms
   11-11 02:31:19.436: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.model.moments.MomentEntity com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.model.moments.zzb.zzfL(android.os.Parcel) took 107.922ms
   11-11 02:31:19.667: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.model.people.PersonEntity com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.model.people.zza.zzfM(android.os.Parcel) took 169.941ms
   11-11 02:31:30.232: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of boolean com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService$Stub.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) took 170.909ms
   11-11 02:31:31.054: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzb.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 327.400ms
   11-11 02:31:31.434: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzc.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 275.692ms
   11-11 02:31:31.817: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzd.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 280.942ms
   11-11 02:31:32.109: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zze.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 141.315ms
   11-11 02:31:33.161: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzf.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 895.272ms
   11-11 02:31:34.304: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzg.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 948.073ms
   11-11 02:31:34.697: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzh.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 303.089ms
   11-11 02:31:35.096: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzi.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 293.232ms
   11-11 02:31:35.483: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzj.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 248.063ms
   11-11 02:31:35.819: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzk.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 266.310ms
   11-11 02:31:36.226: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzl.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 261.331ms
   11-11 02:31:36.609: W/dex2oat(1476): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzm.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 250.717ms
   11-11 02:31:51.611: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void android.UnusedStub.<init>() took 110.472ms
   11-11 02:31:51.815: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of java.lang.String android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat.capabilityToString(int) took 145.742ms
   11-11 02:32:00.375: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of java.util.List android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat.getInstalledAccessibilityServiceList(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager) took 352.172ms
   11-11 02:32:30.606: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqf$zze.<init>(java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.List, java.util.List) took 146.855ms
   11-11 02:32:31.245: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrc$zza$zza com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrb.zza(java.util.List, java.lang.Object) took 184.287ms
   11-11 02:32:32.218: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of int com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrg.zzc(int, com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrn) took 120.846ms
   11-11 02:32:34.452: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu.zza(byte[]) took 137.128ms
   11-11 02:32:41.305: I/art(351): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2425(171KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 8MB/8MB, paused 7.155ms total 195.749ms
   11-11 02:32:41.440: I/art(351): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 54(2656B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 8MB/8MB, paused 12.344ms total 129.632ms
   11-11 02:32:41.466: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of com.google.android.gms.plus.model.moments.ItemScope$Builder com.google.android.gms.plus.model.moments.ItemScope$Builder.setDuration(java.lang.String) took 425.054ms
   11-11 02:32:43.007: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zza.zzb(com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zza) took 224.996ms
   11-11 02:32:44.053: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcp.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqf$zzc, com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.DataLayer, com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzt$zza, com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzt$zza, com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzah) took 101.172ms
   11-11 02:32:44.213: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzbw com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcp.zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.zzag$zza, java.util.Set, com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzdi) took 158.437ms
   11-11 02:32:46.901: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of com.google.android.gms.wearable.internal.GetChannelOutputStreamResponse[] com.google.android.gms.wearable.internal.zzah.zzkh(int) took 123.125ms
   11-11 02:32:55.490: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of boolean android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallback.onMenuOpened(int, android.view.Menu) took 207.450ms
   11-11 02:33:00.397: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of boolean android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter.onSubMenuSelected(android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder) took 384.889ms
   11-11 02:33:12.951: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of boolean com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesCallbacks$Stub.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) took 103.858ms
   11-11 02:33:14.826: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of boolean com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService$Stub.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) took 411.768ms
   11-11 02:33:16.155: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzb.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 171.732ms
   11-11 02:33:16.426: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzc.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 247.101ms
   11-11 02:33:16.698: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzd.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 267.074ms
   11-11 02:33:16.981: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzf.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 135.380ms
   11-11 02:33:17.252: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzg.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 227.297ms
   11-11 02:33:17.529: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzh.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 258.643ms
   11-11 02:33:17.787: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzi.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 241.239ms
   11-11 02:33:18.036: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzj.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 233.587ms
   11-11 02:33:18.287: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void      com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzk.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 246.552ms
   11-11 02:33:18.521: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzl.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 216.133ms
   11-11 02:33:18.814: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzai$zzm.zzc(byte[], byte[]) took 279.531ms
   11-11 02:33:34.321: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of boolean com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.zzi$zza.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) took 149.938ms
   11-11 02:33:35.036: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of boolean com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.zzj$zza$zza.isGeodesic() took 383.782ms
   11-11 02:33:52.509: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.InvitationRef.getInvitationId() took 216.617ms
   11-11 02:33:52.713: W/dex2oat(1476): Compilation of com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Participant com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.InvitationRef.getInviter() took 201.659ms
```

**console output:-**

```
[2015-11-11 02:30:06 - Map1] ------------------------------
[2015-11-11 02:30:06 - Map1] Android Launch!
[2015-11-11 02:30:06 - Map1] adb is running normally.
[2015-11-11 02:30:06 - Map1] Performing com.example.map1.MainActivity activity launch
[2015-11-11 02:30:07 - Map1] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5556' running compatible AVD 'mario'
[2015-11-11 02:30:07 - Map1] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2015-11-11 02:30:07 - Map1] Device API version is 21 (Android 5.0.2)
[2015-11-11 02:30:07 - Map1] Uploading Map1.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2015-11-11 02:30:15 - Map1] Installing Map1.apk...
[2015-11-11 02:32:32 - Map1] Failed to install Map1.apk on device 'emulator-5556!
[2015-11-11 02:32:32 - Map1] (null)
[2015-11-11 02:32:33 - Map1] Launch canceled!
```

**MainActivity class:-**

```
package com.example.map1;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**Android_manifest:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.map1" >
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
  <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCI6bvnLSQ_0DmNEZPn7w8J7FW7_j0nLAQ" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Everything seems to be correct according to that post, I tried it on emulator and real device,but it says unfortunately stopped.