# Android studio is not deploying my app to emulator / device

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated android studio 1.3 to 1.5(1.5 downloaded from stable channel) and now created new project it is compiling fine but not deploying on the device and emulator.Here is the log cat image
[image]

Comment: This is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error

Comment: My bad.I did not mention any launcher activity in manifest.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Kindly check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your activity in the manifest file in order for it to be accessible to the system. To declare your activity, open your manifest file and add an `<activity>` element as a child of the `<application>` element.

```
    <manifest ... >
  <application ... >
      <activity android:name=".ExampleActivity" />
      ...
  </application ... >
  ...
</manifest >
```

When you create a new application using the Android SDK tools, the stub activity that's created for you automatically includes an intent filter that declares the activity responds to the **`"main"`** action and should be placed in the **`"launcher"`** category.

```
<activity android:name=".ExampleActivity" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```