# Why onlineMovieApp crash in mobile when it runs in Android Studio Emulator without error?

Tags: android, android-manifest, logcat, android-logcat

Actually, I'm trying to make a movie app with TMDb API. It shows movies poster in starting when I**t runs in emulater without error. But when I run in mobile it does not works** and shows "unfortunately app has stopped" message. 
/------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
/----------------------
```

**Logcat Varbose n Debug**

```
03-02 07:53:16.513 25321-25321/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni    
03-02 07:53:16.602 25321-25321/com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp-1/lib/x86    
03-02 07:53:16.778 25321-25341/com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true    
03-02 07:53:16.934 25321-25341/com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so    
03-02 07:53:16.936 25321-25341/com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so    
03-02 07:53:16.948 25321-25341/com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so    
03-02 07:53:17.067 25321-25341/com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4    
03-02 07:53:17.230 25321-25341/com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-02 07:53:17.230 25321-25341/com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xed760740, error=EGL_SUCCESS    
03-02 07:53:17.778 25321-25321/com.santossingh.popularmoviesapp W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
```

Comment: When it shows *unfortunately app has stopped*, at the same moment it would give you a very good reason of that in logcat in form of stacktrace . Can you post that? You should also check if have any filter set in the logcat. If so remove that.

Comment: No-Filters Error :

[ 20956/? E/memtrack:  *Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)*

20956/? E/android.os.Debug:  *failed to load memtrack module: -2*

418-718/? E/NetlinkEvent:  *NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found*

21017/? E/memtrack:  *Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)*

21017/? E/android.os.Debug: *failed to load memtrack module: -2*

Comment: 21012/? E/android.os. *Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2*

1106-1266/com.android.launcher3 E/Surface: *getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xded761c0*

418-718/? E/NetlinkEvent: *NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found* ]

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error