# I made application flasshlight but tells me unfortunately application is stopped working

Tags: java, android-studio

I have emulator but is super slow(AMD CPU)

Ok so here is code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpower);
private Camera cam1;
Camera.Parameters params;
private boolean isOn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cam1 = Camera.open();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isOn) {
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                cam1.setParameters(params);
                cam1.stopPreview();
                isOn = false;
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);


            } else {
                params = cam1.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                cam1.setParameters(params);
                cam1.stopPreview();
                isOn = true;
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

}

Comment: Show the stacktrace with crash

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. Post the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare button inside `onCreate`and below `setContentView`. Furthermore, in your **else** condition , instead of `cam1.stopPreview();` you should put `cam1.startPreview();`.In your **if** condition,make sure you put `cam1.release();` below `cam1.stopPreview();`. Make sure you've added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

this in your manifest.xml

Comment: It should be inside **onCreate** because that's where you're placing the view.
Like this,
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpower); `

Comment: No,same problem

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Stack trace is logcat,no?

Comment: Yes! I just went through your stack trace and I think the problem you're getting might be because of `E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module`. This error usually occurs either because of emulator configurations or because the project has organization problem. I'll suggest you go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22745487/6943705) and see if it helps you solve the problem.

Comment: I think it supports API 15+ but you can always check using this `Boolean isFlashAvailable = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager() .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);`

Comment: I tested on real device(Samsung galaxy s4) so i think problem is in organization i will  google it.