# failed to load memtrack module: -2

Tags: android, admob

Despite updating the Google Ad Mobile implementation and package renaming, I still have this error. How to settle it?

10-18 19:05:05.985 12146-12146/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-18 19:05:05.986 12146-12146/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't load memtrack module Logcat Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error)

Comment: Thanks you guy :)