# Trying to use debug malloc for memory leak detection in Android O

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-8.0-oreo

As you probably know, starting Android O, you can use debug versions of `malloc` in order to inspect memory usage in native codes. We can use these info in order to find memory leaks in native code which is really useful. Tutorials are available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/malloc_debug/README.md).

I have tried this tutorial both in emulator and a real device and it successfully enables memory tracing. But problem is that application will not load after enabling this feature and `logcat` show following error:

```
E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
```

and app will load again when I disable debug version of `malloc`, so it is obviously connected to setting this option.

I have searched this error and found few topics like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error) one, but sadly it could not solve my problem. Has anyone else ever encountered this problem? Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Hi, do you find any news with your problem? I curious with the debugging memory in C++ on Android, too. Thank you so much

Comment: @seal2002 I could not get this working, though I didn't spend too much time after this thread on that problem. But you can use AddressSanitizer. I were able to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for information. I glad to heard you can use ASAN to get it working. I have tried with ASan but not able to get it working. I have the question at [here](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/933#issuecomment-613155224). Could you please share the tip to make ASAN works?

Comment: @seal2002 Yes, this asan script is old and I worked hard in google forums to make it work. I have another thread for this and google ref is already updated for it.

Comment: @you can check them here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54550668/cannot-debug-app-when-using-wrapper-script and https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/wrap-script

Comment: @seal2002 above comment :D

Comment: Thanks Afshin for those answer :D